# Como exportar dos componentes de firebase

Tags: firebase

tengo una duda, no se como podria exportar dos componentes (Si se llaman asi) de firebase, en mi caso son: auth y firestore,

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x-x",
  authDomain: "x-x.x.x",
  projectId: "x-x",
  storageBucket: "x-x.x.x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x",
  measurementId: "x-x"
};
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export default {auth, db}
```

Cuando estoy trabajando en otro archivo y quiero importar el componente usando:

```
import {  db } from "firebase/firestore";
```

Me sale un error diciendome lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo importo asi:

```
import  {db}  from "../firebase";
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Estás usando la librería para Cliente en Frontend? Si es así, usas React o tienes alguna configuración extra de compilación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que sustituir

```
export default {auth, db}
```

Por

```
export {auth, db}
```

Para importarlo usas esta forma

```
import  {db}  from "../firebase";
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente tienes una inicialización incorrecta, debe ser `const db = getFirestore(app)`:

```
...
...
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
//const db = getFirestore();
const db = getFirestore(app);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export default {auth, db}
...
...
```

ahora para importar desde otro componente suponiendo que la inicialización se realiza en el archivo `firebaseConfig.js` ubicado en el directorio `src/firebase`:

```
import { db } from './firebase/firebaseConfig.js';
```